# There are no commands defined in the "code" namespace

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

When I try to do a git commit this message appears in my console and will not let me commit.

```
[2018-09-10 07:39:36] local.ERROR: There are no commands defined in the "code" namespace. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Exception\\CommandNotFoundException(code: 0): There are no commands defined in the \"code\" namespace. at /var/www/html/MapadoCarro/new-plataform/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:564)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/html/MapadoCarro/new-plataform/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(604): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->findNamespace('code')
#1 /var/www/html/MapadoCarro/new-plataform/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(229): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->find('code:lint')
#2 /var/www/html/MapadoCarro/new-plataform/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(148): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#3 /var/www/html/MapadoCarro/new-plataform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(88): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#4 /var/www/html/MapadoCarro/new-plataform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(121): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#5 /var/www/html/MapadoCarro/new-plataform/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#6 {main}
"}
```

The project is working normally I just can not commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you setup a pre-commit hook that runs php unit tests and shows these errors due to a misconfiguration? Have a look in `your-project/.git/hooks/` and see if a `pre-commit` file exists.

For more information on git hooks see the [official git-hooks docs here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).